# Cumulative count(*) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a SQL table `votes`, with two columns `vote` and `time`; `vote` is a string, `time` is a timestamp. I'd like to retrieve a "cumulative count" from the table. So, the table looks like this:

```
vote       | time
-----------+----------------
stuart     | 1443000000
stuart     | 1443000000
bryan      | 1443000000
stuart     | 1443000001
bryan      | 1443000001
bryan      | 1443000002
bryan      | 1443000002
```

so, "stuart" gets two votes in the first time interval and "bryan" gets one; they get one each in the second interval, and bryan gets two more in the third, and thus the output results I would like are these:

```
vote       | time         | cumulative total
-----------+--------------+-----------------
stuart     | 1443000000   | 2
bryan      | 1443000000   | 1
stuart     | 1443000001   | 3
bryan      | 1443000001   | 2
stuart     | 1443000002   | 3
bryan      | 1443000002   | 4
```

I'm not sure how to do this. Obviously, getting how many votes happened in each time interval is trivial (`SELECT vote, time, COUNT(*) from table GROUP BY time, vote ORDER BY time, vote`) but making a *cumulative* count seems harder. Is there a way to do so?

(I'm using MySQL, and am happy to use MySQL-specific functions here if useful.)

Comment: Using a correlated sub-query for the counting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a correlated sub-query to do the counting:

```
select distinct vote, time, (select count(*) from table t2
                             where t2.vote = t1.vote
                               and t2.time <= t1.time)
from table t1
```

Comment: FROM t1 directly,you dont need teh TABLE keyword

Comment: @Mihai, I don't get you here? Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Also it wont work since t1.vote=t2.vote will create a cross join and your distinct will remove desired rows

Comment: The table is called "table", and it's the same table used twice, with table-alias t1 and t2,

Comment: Of course it's working and the DISTINCT **is** needed

Comment: Hopefully the op didn't really want the `stuart     | 1443000002   | 3` row shown in the result :-)

Comment: @dnoeth ah, I would like that row, indeed -- but your point is valid, that if there's no "stuart" entry for that timestamp at _all_ then it'll be much harder to produce that row... so I can live without that row if I must.

Comment: @jarlh clever. I wouldn't have thought of that! Answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 8 introduced support for [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/), which are the perfect tool for cumulative sums. They will perform *much* better than the alternatives using correlated subqueries. Your desired query can be written as follows:

```sql
SELECT
  vote,
  time,
  sum(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY vote ORDER BY time)
FROM table
GROUP BY time, vote
ORDER BY time, vote
```

Note that the inner `count(*)` is an ordinary aggregate function, which is nested in the outer `sum(...) OVER (...)` window function. This is possible because [aggregate functions are logically calculated before window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you really need that `stuart | 1443000002 | 3` row then you can do this:

```
select distinct vote, time,
       (select count(*) from `table` t2
        where t2.vote = t1.vote
        and t2.time <= t1.time) `cumulative total`
from   (select distinct t3.vote vote, t4.time time
        from `table` t3, `table` t4) t1;
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/960d6/11/0

What we need to do is make a table that contains EVERY combination of names and times (a join with no conditions) and then calculate the counts from the original table using all those combinations.

Thanks to @jarlh for the query in his answer - not having to start from scratch saved a bunch of time.