# Grafana with MySQL exponential growth graph

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table to record the number of users

| id | email | name | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1@example.com | John | 2019-02-05 18:53:50.000000 |
| 2 | user2@example.com | Rock | 2019-02-06 18:53:50.000000 |
| 3 | user3@example.com | Sena | 2019-02-08 18:53:50.000000 |
| 4 | user4@example.com | Anny | 2019-02-08 18:53:50.000000 |

I want to get the exponential growth in count per day

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-02-05 | 1 |
| 2019-02-06 | 2 |
| 2019-02-07 | 2 |
| 2019-02-08 | 4 |

And draw a similar graph on the Grafana portal

[image]

I tried using `count()` but it gives the count of data per day

[image]

The query generated on Graphana is

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) DIV 86400 * 86400 AS "time",
  count(id) AS "Verified"
FROM custom_domain_customdomain
WHERE
  is_cname_verified = '1' AND
  is_txt_verified = '1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) DIV 86400 * 86400
```

Comment: You need cumulative sum of counts with filling the missing days with 0 counts. A similar question to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735294/cumulative-count-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the steps to create your cumulative count based on a contiguous date range.

The `date_range` CTE is based on one of the [RECURSIVE CTE examples in the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series)

The second CTE is a fairly straightforward LEFT JOIN from the `date_range` to your `users` table to do the count of new users per day.

The final SELECT query uses SUM() as a window function to give the cumulative user count.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
`date_range` (`date`) AS (
    -- retrieve minimum date from users for start of date_range
    SELECT DATE(MIN(`users`.`created`)) FROM `users`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    FROM    `date_range`   
    -- retrieve maximum date from users for end of date_range
    WHERE   `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= (SELECT DATE(MAX(`users`.`created`)) FROM `users`)
),
`users_per_day` AS (
    SELECT
        `date_range`.`date` AS `created_date`,
        COUNT(`users`.`id`) AS `new_user_count`
    FROM `date_range`
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`created` BETWEEN `date_range`.`date` AND (`date_range`.`date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
    GROUP BY `date_range`.`date`
)

SELECT
    `created_date`,
    `new_user_count`,
    SUM(`new_user_count`) OVER (ORDER BY `created_date`) as `cumulative_count`
FROM `users_per_day`;
```

The users_per_day CTE and final SELECT can be combined but I have left them separate as it clearly shows the steps used and the overhead is negligible.